Using JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme for multiple roles?
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer("Admin", options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
            {
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    
                ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Token:Audience"],
                ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Token:Issuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Token:SecurityKey"])),
                LifetimeValidator = (notBefore, expires, securityToken, validationParameters) => expires != null ? expires > DateTime.UtcNow : false,
    
                NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.Name
            };
        });
    
    
    
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Admin")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AllCar()
{
    return Ok(_carRepository.GetAll());
}
        
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "User")]
[HttpGet("ForUser")]
public IActionResult ForUser()
{
    return Ok(_carRepository.GetAll());
}

I want to set up for the user role, how can I do it?
Even if I logged in with admin or user, it just looked at whether it was Authorized. Without looking at the role, his enpoints returned with the code 200.

Have you looked at role based authorization in asp.net core ?

Thanks, I tried it now. There is no problem for the role I specified, but when I send a request with another role, it returns 403 code. Shouldn't it be 401?

403 Forbidden means that the server was successful in authenticating the caller (i.e. the JWT was valid) but the caller doesn't have the necessary permissions to view the content. So from your description that makes sense to me unless I'm misunderstanding something

I understand, if it works for me it's best not to deal with it for now :D. I will continue to research the subject, thanks.
